# imagemap area with javascript referencing a form value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, imagemap

I'm trying to create an image map that acts as an up/down incrementer/decrementer control. The image is a simple 16x16 png file with two triangles (one pointing up, the other pointing down) with the top half of the image for UP (increment) and the lower half for DOWN (decrement).

The code below illustrates the trouble I'm having with the href of the imagemap area that references the form value. I am puzzled why the call to the alert function works whilst the code that uses the form value for the actual incrementing/decrementing is failing. The actual code I intend to implement will have more complexity but I need to get past this roadblock or change approach before going deeper.

So, I'm wondering whether this approach is indeed possible and if there's perhaps just something small missing from my scenario, or if perhaps this is a misguided attempt at doing something that would be better accomplished in another manner. I'll also confess my relative newbie status when it comes to client-side programming (as if it were not obvious) and thank everyone in advance for their gentle and constructive guidance.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ImageMap Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <fieldset>
    <legend>ImageMap area href for javascript works for alerts:</legend>
    <input type='text' name='foo1_filter' size='25' value='123' />
    <img src='../img/arrow_up-down.png' title='Up-Down' usemap='#foo1' />
    <map name='foo1'>
     <area shape='rect' coords='0,0,15,7' href='javascript:alert("UP");' />
     <area shape='rect' coords='8,0,15,15' href='javascript:alert("DOWN");' />
    </map>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
  <p />
  <form>
   <fieldset>
    <legend>ImageMap area href for javascript does not work when referencing form values:</legend>
    <input type='text' name='foo2_filter' size='25' value='123' />
    <img src='../img/arrow_up-down.png' title='Up-Down' usemap='#foo2' />
    <map name='foo2'>
     <area shape='rect' coords='0,0,15,7' href='javascript:this.form.foo2_filter.value++;' />
     <area shape='rect' coords='8,0,15,15' href='javascript:this.form.foo2_filter.value--;' />
    </map>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks to Andrea and kmb385 for their suggestions. As a result, everything is now working as expected. I will post the completed code shortly (my newbie status imposes an 8 hour wait). The changes I made to get it to work were:
1. made an explicit reference to a form name
2. set href='#'
3. put the javascript action into an onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in the use of this.form within an area element. The .form attribute can be used only when clicking/using form elements, like inputs, fields, etc. Try doing the following:

1. Add a name to the form, e.g.: my_form
2. Change the "this.form" to "document.my_form"

Something like

```
<form name="my_form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>ImageMap area href for javascript does not work when referencing form values:</legend>
    <input type='text' name='foo2_filter' size='25' value='123' />
    <img src='../img/arrow_up-down.png' title='Up-Down' usemap='#foo2' />
    <map name='foo2'>
      <area shape='rect' coords='0,0,15,7' href='javascript:document.my_form.foo2_filter.value++;' />
      <area shape='rect' coords='8,0,15,15' href='javascript:document.my_form.foo2_filter.value--;' />
    </map>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Regards

Comment: Does it matter that the decremented value is never assigned to the DOM element's value attribute?

Comment: Actually it is; javascript parses the value of the field and increments/decrements it: foo++ is equal to foo=foo+1

Comment: The incremented/decremented value is used as a search filter, and when the form is submitted the value gets passed as a parameter to another page which presents search results. I see the error in how it was originally coded and have it working correctly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

- The DOM element is improperly accessed through Javascript.
- The new value is never assigned to the DOM element.
- The Javascript is inline. Note* This is more a standards issue.

Try setting the value as follows:

```
<area shape='rect' coords='0,0,15,7' href='javascript:document.forms[0].elements["foo2_filter"].value = --document.forms[0].elements["foo2_filter"].value;' />
```

A few things to notice about this code.

- The `--` prefixed decrement operator is used so that the value is reduced prior to assignment.
- The `=` operator is used to assign the value property of the DOM element with the decremented value.

Take a look at this page about reference DOM elements in a form:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.phtml

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="fooForm2">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>ImageMap area href for javascript referencing form values:</legend>
    <input type='text' name='foo2_filter' size='25' value='123' />
    <img src='../img/arrow_up-down.png' title='Up-Down' usemap='#foo2' />
    <map name='foo2'>
      <area shape='rect' coords='0,0,15,7' href='#' onclick='javascript:document.fooForm2.foo2_filter.value++; return false' />
      <area shape='rect' coords='0,8,15,15' href='#' onclick='javascript:document.fooForm2.foo2_filter.value--; return false' />
    </map>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Thanks to Andrea and kmb385 for their suggestions. As a result, everything is now working as expected. The changes I made to get it to work were:

1. made an explicit reference to a form name
2. set href='#'
3. put the javascript action into an onclick
4. used proper DOM element referencing
5. fixed area coords for bottom portion of the image map